# Can I open a new connection in a main transaction?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection

I have the following scenario in Java JDBC based transaction (in 200 user based Java web application).

Please advice whether the following approach is correct:

1. Open a main transaction ---
2. Results in a value
3. Based on the above value an insert or update should happen(this insert should persist irrespective of the failure of main transaction
4. So I open atomic transaction (a new connection and a transaction to execute and commit the values)
5. Close the connection
6. In case of failure roll-back the steps 5-1
7. If success continue with the main transaction
8. If a failure occurs roll-back only main and not the child since the child is already committed.

I am worried about the performance and other issues related to my approach.

Comment: The approach is correct.  Did you have any other questions?

Answer (score 0):

I think your transaction performance will depends of many factors, and is totally related to how you develop every step.

By Example, it makes difference if you use a Connection Pool or not, or if you use PreparedStatement or not, or if you use Stored Procedures or not, etc.

The sequence of your approach seems to be right if that is the way that works for you :)

You may evaluate if the DB related issues helps if you use pools, prepared statements, etc.

If you need to optimize your application, you can use a Profiler, there are some post around here related to profilers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101680/free-profiler-for-java

Regards.